# Display UDP(RGB) Input to ffmpeg or vlc

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, rgb, vlc

I receive from local port UDP packets that content only RGB payload (video stream).

How can I display RGB using ffmpeg or vlc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope these help, even though they don't directly answer your question. They give pointers to command line options that are needed to handle raw rgb data with ffmpeg and gstreamer.

1. I once needed to receive rgb frames from a webcam connected to another computer.
2. Couldn't work with UDP, because without framing, the packets got dropped, frames became incomplete, rows out of sync. Hence TCP (using UDP is a matter or changing that word in the commands).

Fighting with ffmpeg, gstreamer, mencoder, mplayer, and vlc yielded the following solution.

*"Architecture":*

[LINUX V4L2 WEBCAM CAPTURE] -> [THEORA VIDEO COMPRESSION] -> [RTP STREAM @ PORT 1233] -> [RECEIVING HOST] -> [THEORA VIDEO DECOMPRESSION] -> [RAW RGB/8BPP TO LOCALHOST @ PORT 1234]

*Command lines:*

```
# VIDEO STREAM SENDING SIDE
vlc -vvv -I dummy --udp-caching=0 --sout-mux-caching=0 --no-audio \
  v4l2:///dev/video0:width=640:height=480:caching=200:fps=10/1 :v4l2-caching=0 \
  ':sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=3000,acodec=none}: \
    rtp{mux=ts,dst=destinationhost,port=1233,caching=0}'

# VIDEO STREAM RECEIVING/FORWARDING TO TCP / ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i rtp://0.0.0.0?localport=1233 \
  -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -vcodec rawvideo tcp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

Alternatively, one command to accomplish them both (with gstreamer):

```
# CAPTURE WEBCAM->FORWARD RGB GRAYSCALE TO TCP / gstreamer
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! ffmpegcolorspace \
  ! video/x-raw-gray, width=320, height=240, 'framerate=(fraction)30/1' \
  ! tcpclientsink host=localhost port=1234
```